# Cannot open a link in new tab

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I am trying to fix this problem, can anyone suggest me what is occurring this ?
http://ls3b.ch/

[image: These are the links, which opens in same window]

This website is build in wordpress, there are some links here which opens in the same page but opening in the new tab will return only these contents, http://ls3b.ch/work/mr16-gu5-3/

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer the question, I noticed that your hierarchy is a bit out, if your using custom post types, you will probably need to do some rewrites to fix that up so your SEO isn't effected too much.

As for your problem about the links, I clicked on every link I could find and couldn't get to the page you linked to as being the problem. It might just be stored in your cache and needing to be cleared.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, its using custom post type with this plugin toolset types https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/
The listing opens in the modal clicking from the main page, but if i copy the link address and open it in the new tab, the whole structure is a mess.

Its not because of cache, you can find the link when you hover over the listing items i have posted in the image above.

Comment: From what I can see, you haven't attached any styles to the code that opens in the new tab. As far as I can tell, these models weren't designed to be opened in a new tab, so there aren't any links to a style sheet at all. There is an empty head tag if you inspect the page, but if you view the source, there isn't a head tag at all. If you link your style sheet to those pages, it should sort itself out